# Add fadeout on several mp4 files with different durations using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to add fadin and fadeout to several mp4 files using ffmpeg.
Problem I think is that ffprobe get's the duration with 3 decimals, for example
36,217.

I got an error saying:
No such filter: '217:d'
I think it's because of the three decimals, anyway to get rid of them?
Here's the batch I'm trying to use:

```
@echo off
    mkdir faded
    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
        ffprobe -i "%%f" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" >dur.txt
        set /p dur=<dur.txt
        del dur.txt
        for /f "delims=" %%g in ('powershell !dur!-1') do set fadetime=%%g
        ffmpeg -i "%%f" -filter:v "fade=t=in:st=0:d=1, fade=t=out:st=!fadetime!:d=1" -filter:a "afade=t=in:st=0:d=1, afade=t=out:st=!fadetime!:d=1" -c:v libx264 -crf 18 "faded/%%~nf.mp4"
    )
```

Comment: It looks like FFprobe uses your regional settings, and returns `36,217`, while FFmpeg expects `36.217`. Try replacing the `,` with `.` (the comma is used as filter separator). Are you really getting `36,217` instead of `36.217`? (it's undocumented).

Comment: It returns 36.217 in cmd, and also in dur.txt. Strange

Comment: Will try to change regional settings and see, maybe the ”set /p dur” has something to do with that.

Comment: Working now when I changed "," to "." in regional settings. Got an another error, that says "Only '-vf fade=t=in:st=0:d=1, fade=t=out:st=28.067:d=1' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters". And also: Only '-af afade=t=in:st=0:d=1, afade=t=out:st=28.067:d=1' read, ignoring remaining -af options: Use ',' to separate filters. But it seems to work anyway, got fade in and out as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. Had to change "," to "." in Windows 10 format settings.